# Two different method outputs the same image

Tags: c#, class, image-processing, properties

I created two Methods in a Class. And one Property for my Image. I'm trying to  add noise to my image then apply my filter. But when i run my code I see result of my filter on two PictureBoxes. Noisy image should be one of the PictureBoxes.

Note:I want to use only one Bitmap if it is possible

```
private void sliderKernel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  Filtreler f1 = new Filtreler();
  f1.Img = new Bitmap(pBox_SOURCE.Image);
  int SablonBoyutu = sliderKernel.Value;
  f1.addnoise();
  pictureBoxNoisyImg.Image = f1.Img;
  f1.meanfilter(SablonBoyutu);
  pBox_PROCESSED.Image = f1.Img;
}
```

```
//MY CLASS FILE
public Bitmap Img { get; set; }

public void addnoise()
{
  //i deleted this parts to make easier to read
  Img.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(randpixelr, randpixelg, randpixelb));
  return;
}

public void meanfilter(int kernelsize )
{ 
  //i deleted this parts to make easier to read
  Img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(ortalamaR, ortalamaG, ortalamaB));
  return;
}
```

Edit:I changed MouseUp Event. And now, it works properly. But i am not sure,maybe some changes can be done too.

```
private void sliderKernel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  Filtreler f1 = new Filtreler();
  f1.Img = new Bitmap(pBox_SOURCE.Image);
  int SablonBoyutu = sliderKernel.Value;
  f1.addnoise();
  pictureBoxNoisyImg.Image = f1.Img;
  Bitmap MeanImg = (Bitmap)f1.Img.Clone();
  f1.meanfilter(SablonBoyutu,MeanImg);
  pBox_PROCESSED.Image = MeanImg;  
}
```

Comment: Setting this: `f1.Img = new Bitmap(pBox_SOURCE.Image);`, you assign an Image to a Field. It points to the actual Image content. When you set this: `pictureBoxNoisyImg.Image = f1.Img;`, you assign an Image by reference. The reference is `Img`. Any change to `Img` is reflected in any object that has a reference to it. A reference is just a number that allows to access the actual object stored in memory using its address. The Image content is not copied. If you need to apply a different filter to the same original Image, duplicate the Image, preferably by Cloning it (see the Docs about it)

Comment: I cloned original image and now it works. Am I using Property named Img properly?

Comment: It appears so. Note that you have 3 Bitmaps object references now: one is  `pBox_SOURCE.Image` the second is held by both `f1.Img` and `pictureBoxNoisyImg.Image` (these point to the same image) and one in `pBox_PROCESSED.Image`. These all occupy memory. When you don't need one of the images anymore, remember to `Dispose()` of it. You can always write something like `f1.Img?.Dispose();` before assigning a new one, so even if `f1.Img` is `null` it won't throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

In c#, the bitmap operates as a reference.

Therefore, you copy the bitmap.

```cs
pictureBox.Image = bitmap.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
                   System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);
```

Also, this must be called to prevent memory leakage.

```cs
if (pictureBox.Image != null)
{
    pictureBox.Image.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thank you i will add memory leakage part. But i didn't understand why my code is not working properly.